# getting error when trying to make dynamic profile pages

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a dynamic profile page, viewable for everyone using link www.example.com/user/$id.

profile pages work they are not public and cant be seen by other people yet. I tried to add this part to the code:

```
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL);

if ($userid) {
    $userinfo = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$userid'");
    print_r($userinfo);
}
?>
```

it displais an error when using the custom link (or basic /profile.php?id=$id).

here is the full profile code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--START HEAD-->
    <?php include 'head.php'; ?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="/profile.css"/>
    <title><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>'s profile</title>
<!--END HEAD-->
</head>
<body>
<!--START BODY-->
<?php
    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        include'navigationbar.php';
    } else {
        include'navigationbar2.php';
    }
?>
<!--MAIN CONTENT-->
<div class="movedown"></div>
<div class="content">


<?php
$userid = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL);

if ($userid) {
    $userinfo = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$userid'");
    print_r($userinfo);
}
?>


<!--MAIN PROFILE-->
<div class="username">
<?php if(empty(htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['clan'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))){
    echo "";
}else{
    echo "[".htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['clan'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."]";} ?>


<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
<div class="fr">ID: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  ?></div></div>
<div class="spacing"></div>


<div class="fl">

<!--####################################### NEED CODE FOR DEFAULT AVATAR AND CUSTOM AVATAR ######################################################-->

<!--AVATAR-->
<div class="avatarback">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="/bin/avatar/default_picture/default.jpg" width="180px"/></div>
</div>

<!--####################################### NEED CODE FOR DEFAULT AVATAR AND CUSTOM AVATAR ######################################################-->


<!--TITLES / SIGNS-->
<div class="signs"><br/>
    <div class="title"><div class="fl">Title:       </div>
<div class="fr"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>       </div></div><!--TITLE-->
        <div class="spacing"></div>


    <div class="warnings"><div class="fl">Warnings: </div>
<div class="fr"><?php 
if($_SESSION['user']['banned'] == 1){
    echo "<div class='red'>Banned</div>";
}else{
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['warnings'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
?>    </div></div><!--WARNINGS-->
        <div class="spacing"></div> 


    <div class="joined"><div class="fl">Joined:     </div>
<div class="fr"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['timestamp'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>  </div></div><!--JOINED-->
</div>
</div>



<div class="padding"></div>

<!--BIO-->
<div class="bioback">
<?php if(empty(htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))){
    echo "This user has not set any bio yet...";
}else{
    echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?>
</div>


<!--SETTINGS TAB-->
<div class="etc-back">
<div><a href="/messages">Message</a></div>
    <div class="spacing2"></div>    
<div><a href="/settings">Settings</a></div>

</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="email">
<div class="fl">E-mail:</div><div class="fr"><a href="mailto:<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry for bad english and the mess.

Comment: `$userid` is *always* set. If it is set to NULL you will query for NULL

Comment: What's the error? I also don't see `session_start()` anywhere.

Comment: Are you using a framework of some sort? Where does the function `query_first()` come from? It is usually just `query()`.

Comment: @HenryA. Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::query_first() in C:\wamp\www\profile.php on line 29 is the error i get and session_start is hidden in the head.php...well in the common.php used to connect to the database. but things like that and css is all placed in head.php so i could easly change it once instead of 60

Comment: @JayBlanchard the first php code i shared was found on stackoverflow and accept as an answer. ive never made any dynamic pages but belived this was the right way.

Comment: `session_start()` must come before anything on the page, you're including it inside the `<head>` tag. `query_first()` is also not a valid PDO function, are you trying to use `query()`?

Comment: @HenryA. yes seession start is placed in head while right under where i include head, i place the code. changing query_first to query worked but gave new error and it still only echo logged in persons info even after page.php?id=2. this is the new error: PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] =&gt; SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '2'
)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables seem to be named differently .. Try naming them the same:

```
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL);

if ($id) {
    $userinfo = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    print_r($userinfo);
}
?>
```

Comment: He's using `$userid` in his second example @Zak.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes this is how i found this part.

Comment: @Zak nope still get the error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::query_first() in C:\wamp\www\profile.php on line 29" its something with the $userinfo = $db->....

Comment: am i even doing the profile.php right? ive never created dynamic pages before, so not sure how i do it. i use the <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['table_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> because i know this is used to display current logged in user. NOT sure if it can be used to echo other members info when using dynamic pages